# HttpRequest throttling between two web apps

Tags: c#, .net-core, httprequest, nancy

I have two webapps running .net core 2.1 self hosted (it's Azure, but the behavior applies also to when I'm running it locally) with NancyFx.

App1 is just a proxy that collects client requests, does authentication, and forwards them to App2 and than sends response back to clients. This architecture is not likely to change due to some internal limitations.

App1 uses HttpClient and HttpClientFactory for forwarding.

Now the problem. I run a load test which generates a lot of requests. In logs I see that App2 is in general fast enough with handling them, but when the load increases App1 is still running into timeouts. I investigated faling requests and see roughly the following:

- 8:30:00 Client request came to App1
- 8:30:01 HttpClient in App1 posted
  request to App2
- 8:30:31 Request accepted by App2 (What? 30 seconds
  when both apps are localhost?!)
- 8:32:00 In App2:
  ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|Connection id
  "0HLFE17I2N0C2", Request id "0HLFE17GH3G4R:00000001": An unhandled
  exception was thrown by the application.
  System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. In
  App1: 503

### Some research:

- In App2 the CPU and RAM remain low

  - In App2 database access is fast and queries are all executed in much under 1 sec
  - In dotTrace I see that lots of time is spent in Nancy.NancyEngine.HandleRequest
  - I added ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100; to both apps
  - I added  `<connectionManagement><add address = "http://localhost:5001" maxconnection = "100"
    /></connectionManagement>`
  - I tried with HttpRequest without factory and passed in HttpRequestHandler with MaxConnections = 100
  - I added this to App2:

    builder.UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
                            {
                                listenOptions.KestrelServerOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 400;
                                listenOptions.KestrelServerOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 400;
                            });
                    });

Nothing helps, it looks to me like throttling, but where? IP of App1 doesn't change of course and probably App2 doesn't like so many requests. But the behavior is the same locally, so it's not some Azure protection.